# iTextSharp form filler works ... kinda

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, pdf-form

I have an XFA enabled PDF document that I would like to fill out programatically. I'm using C# and iTextSharp 5.5.12.0

The document is password protected so I set                 PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;

The file I'm working with is the [N-400](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/n-400.pdf?download=1).

The filled document has the fields set properly when I view it in Adobe Acrobat Reader. But if I open it in a browser (say IE or Chrome) the fields are empty.

I am opening the file in append mode.

Here's my code (SRC, XML and DEST are strings with full paths to the files).

```
        using (FileStream pdf = new FileStream(SRC, FileMode.Open))
        using (FileStream xml = new FileStream(XML, FileMode.Open))
        using (FileStream filledPdf = new FileStream(DEST, FileMode.Create))
        {
            PdfReader.unethicalreading = true;
            PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
            pdfReader.RemoveUsageRights();

            PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, filledPdf, '\0', true);
            string[] fields = stamper.AcroFields.Fields.Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
            for (int key = 0; key <= fields.Count() - 1; key++)
            {
                stamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(fields[key], "setfflags", PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY, null);
            }
            stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;

            stamper.AcroFields.Xfa.FillXfaForm(xml);
            stamper.Close();
            pdfReader.Close();
        }
```

Comment: Here's the XML document:

<form1>
<Line1_AlienNumber>987654321</Line1_AlienNumber>
<P2_Line6_USCISELISAcctNumber>123456789</P2_Line6_USCISELISAcctNumber>
</form1>

Comment: your form appears to be a hybrid form, I.e. there both is a AcroForm and a XFA form representation in the pdf. You only fill the XFA form in your code, so the AcroForm representation remains empty. Adobe acrobat reader prefers the XFA form during display. Many other pdf viewers don't support XFA, though, and only use the AcroForm form for display. So you get the filled form in acrobat and the empty form elsewhere.

Comment: Please read the FAQ entry [Is it safe to remove XFA?](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/it-safe-remove-xfa) I think yours is a case where the XFA part should be thrown away.